# Maximo Automation Script for Integration - JSON

Tags: javascript, integration, maximo

I'm writing a script for integration to modify JSON input and save to maximo. First I converted the StructureData erData input to JSON object like this;

`var resp = JSON.parse(erData.getDataAsString());`

Then I modified the JSON object to add additional properties. How can I convert back my modified JSON object to StructureData erData so that I can save it to Maximo.

Thank you. Regards

Comment: As an aside, the JSON Mapping application in Maximo might allow you to do the same thing without the need for code, depending on how complicated the thing you are doing is.

Comment: You could improve the quality of your question by showing some more code. You can protect your privacy by using generic names and/or values, but it would help us help you and help your question benefit other users if you supplied a [example].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To convert back the modified JSON object to StructureData erData by using `JSON.stringify()` javaScript method as follows :

***Say***, your `resp` has following stringify data : `'{"result":true, "count":42}'`

```
var resp = JSON.parse(erData.getDataAsString());  // resp = '{"result":true, "count":42}';
resp['name'] = 'Dummy';                           // a new property with key name and value Dummy is created and added in resp
console.log(resp);                                // you get the new resp object
console.log(JSON.stringify(resp));                // '{"result":true, "count":42, "name":"Dummy"}'
```

In case for Maximo to work, follow the [JSON String from JSON Object  Maximo](https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/creating-json-string-json-object-and-json-arrays-automation-scripts)

Hope this helps !!

Comment: Yes, I did that earlier. Unfortunately, maximo couldn't process that as it is read as string type. Here is the error: "java.lang.String incompatible with psdi.iface.mic.StructureData"

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [Maximo JavaDocs](https://developer.ibm.com/static/site-id/155/maximodev/7609/maximocore/businessobjects/) for StructureData, and not being sure how thorough it is, you could try `StructureData(JSON.stringify(resp))`. If that doesn't work, you may need to convert your JSON to XML and pass the XML as a byte array to a StructureData constructor.

Alternatively, use the `StructureData` methods to manipulate `erData` directly, without converting to/from JSON.